# Angular-UI and PassportJS Authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, passport.js, passport-local

So I'm trying to get local-auth working with passport and angular-ui but I think i've confused myself.  I believe local-signup and local-login work because the redirects are working as expected.

I have a small Auth service that I want to inject and use to store the user information. it looks like this:

```js
myApp.factory('Auth', function() {
  var user;

  return {
    setUser: function(aUser) {
      user = aUser;
    },
    isLoggedIn: function() {
      return (user) ? user : false;
    }
  }
});
```

My routes look like this:

```js
    app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          console.log(user);
          var param = 'There was an error with your login';
          return res.redirect('/#/login?valid=' + param);
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
          }
          //console.log(req);
          console.log(user);
          return res.redirect('/#/news');
        });
      })(req, res, next);
    });
```

My states look like this:

```js
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/news");

  $stateProvider
    .state('news', {
      url: "/news",
      templateUrl: "templates/news.html",
      params: {
        message: null
      }

    })
    .state('people', {
      url: "/people",
      templateUrl: "templates/people.html",
      resolve: {
        authenticate: authenticate
      },
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html"
    })
    .state('signup', {
      url: "/signup",
      templateUrl: "templates/signup.html"
    })
    .state('preLogin', {
      url: "/preLogin",
      templateUrl: "templates/preLogin.html"
    });

  function authenticate($q, Auth, $state, $timeout) {
    if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      return $q.when()
    } else {
      $timeout(function() {
        $state.go('login')
      })
      return $q.reject()
    }
  }
});
```

I don't know how or when to store the user information in my Auth service.  I assume I need to do this in the loginCtrl but I don't know how to tell when its a successful login besides the URL redirects.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a link to the full project: 
https://github.com/rcbgit/boiler

Comment: you could use http response status instead of redirect , return status code and data , when login success 200 and user data.